# How to use Raspbee + Raspberry pi (3 B+) + GPRS Shield(SIM7600E-H 4G HAT)

Tags: pi-3

On Raspberry pi, I want to use Raspbee as zigbee controller and SIM7600E-H 4G HAT as GPRS shield for network data

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Waveshare-4G-Raspberry-SIM7600E-H-Supports/dp/B07F1NSGQ8/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?_encoding=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0&th=1

https://www.amazon.co.uk/RaspBee-premium-ZigBee-Raspberry-Firmware/dp/B00E6300DO/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?_encoding=UTF8&%2AVersion%2A=1&%2Aentries%2A=0

How do I achieve that?

To enable zigbee controller I use the proprietary REST API coming from Dresden Elektronik and when i use raspbee alone with raspberry pi, it works perfect and I am able to detect the sensors. But with these all three, the zigbee controller does not work. I am not sure if I have connected the GPIO headers properly, but I see red led light glowing when I connect all these and power on. Please refer the image, [image]

Comment: Ah, let me read the friendly manual: https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/9/8/e/b/c935cac12f9a2115d11cc17ce826c4b388f7.pdf.

Comment: The manual says Rpi2/3 are supported, but no mentioning of Rpi4B.

Comment: GPIO pins of Rpi4B is same as Rpi2/3, so there should be no hardware incompatibility problem. But firmware might be out of date. The user manual seems to say the the green LED should be blinking. Is it not so?

Comment: @tlfong01- I am using Rpi3B+ and I have no problem when using the raspbee alone with Rpi3B+ and dresenden software. It works perfectly. Problem is only when I use it along with the GPRS shield. As per the user manual, green LED light blinks while boot loading and then red LED light glows states that the raspbee has been loaded successfully and connected to firmware. This is happening in both the cases. I am not sure where it goes wrong

Comment: I see. SIM7600 and RaspBee works with Rpi separately, but not all three at the same time. So there might be some hardware or software clashes. Then you need to read the manuals again to find out where is the clash.